# How to annotate a training phrase with @sys.any system entity in Dialogflow CX usign Java client library

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx, client-library

How to add system entity entity type in the intent parameter to set in training phrase. sys.any does not have any id.

Tried using sys.any @sys.any as entity type id but didnt work. We have ids for custom entitys but didnt see a specific id for sys.any entity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.